# How to increase character limit in readline in R?

Tags: r

So, I am writing a small gaming function in R using the readline function to allow for users to do text based decisions. My issue is that readline has a character limit (256 to be specific). The help page for the function says it can be extended in the source code. My issue is that I am struggling to pull up the source code. I have tried a few different methods but nothing is working. The most I ever get for the source code is as follows

```
>getAnywhere('readline') 

A single object matching ‘readline’ was found
It was found in the following places
package:base
namespace:base
with value

function (prompt = "") 
.Internal(readline(prompt))
<bytecode: 0x32e0e68>
<environment: namespace:base>
```

Any help would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: I'm not sure, but the easy option seems to be using `cat` or other functions to show the prompt?

Comment: Interesting question. The doc appears to be misleading, since [the source](https://github.com/wch/r-source) does not appear to be readily editable in this regard. However, @Consistency's recommendation is most likely the easiest/best workaround: since it does not automatically append a newline, it should be easy to replace `reply <- readline(long_string)` with `cat(long_string); reply <- readline('');`.

Answer (score 0):

the help file is quite clear on this one:

> **Details**
>
> The prompt string will be truncated to a maximum allowed
> length, normally 256 chars (but can be changed in the source code).

The remaining question is would you actually want to rebuild R for this? Or use `cat` as @Consistency has suggested? I tried to find the source file where readline is defined by searching Brian's R github using this query: `repo:wch/r-source readline` and get that the following :

https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/2d66ebe393fed6fadfb2417796c7d42654cdb465/src/library/utils/src/io.c

Where it looks like the global

```
/* NB:  in Windows this also needs to be set in gnuwin32/getline/getline.c */
#define CONSOLE_PROMPT_SIZE 256
```

Is the bottleneck on the prompt size.